# Including directories for doxygen documentation

Tags: doxygen, include-path

I have a collection of `.dox` documentation files for my project
in a dox directory as illustrated below

In the input section I have included `../` for doxygen to pick up the source code. However when I put `./` it does not pick up my documentation files and have to include each file. Is there a way to include them automatically?

Here is the `docs` and `lib` directories. In `lib` I have the source code, whereas in `docs` I have the documentation.

```
../
├── docs
│   ├── dox
│   └── Doxyfile
└── lib
```

Here is the contents of the `dox` directory

```
./dox/
├── gnu_affero_gpl.dox
├── gnu_fdl.dox
├── gnu_gpl.dox
├── larsa
│   └── larsa_core.dox
├── larsa.dox
├── meidum
│   ├── lattices
│   ├── lattices.dox
│   ├── lattices.dox~
│   ├── polyhedra
│   └── polyhedra.dox
├── meidum.dox
├── modules.dox
└── vikingr.dox
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed the problem. The solution was to remember to add `*.dox` in `FILE_PATTERNS` variable in `Doxyfile`.